# Set a return value as variable in window batch

Tags: batch-file, window, command

How can I use if else statement to echo if value more than 1?

```
@echo off

setlocal
set "sql=c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe"
for /f "usebackq" %%a in (`%sql% -u root -ss -e "select COUNT(*) FROM mytable"      mydatabase`) do set TESTVAR=%%a

if %TESTVAR% GEQ 1 (echo Database has already existed.) else echo import 

pause
```

Comment: wrap your sql statement in a `FOR` loop. Show the output of running that command to get more specific details.

Comment: How? can you give me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kind of like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "sql=c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe"
for /f "usebackq" %%a in (`%sql% -u root -ss -e "select COUNT^(*^) FROM browser" form_generator`) do set TESTVAR=%%a
if %TESTVAR% LSS 1 echo whatever
pause
```