# How To make looping from return mysql on windows

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

on linux i can make looping result from select mariadb like this.

```
data=$(mysql -uroot -pdemo -sNe "select name from employee;");
for datas on $data
do
   printf "${datas}";
done
```

how to do that on windows (.bat or powershell). I have experience looping but result from `dir` like this.

```
set mysqlDataDir="D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.14\data"
pushd "%mysqlDataDir%"
for /d %%f in (*) do (
    echo processing folder "%%f"
)
popd
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set a return value as variable in window batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22817571/set-a-return-value-as-variable-in-window-batch)

Comment: Yes I got some clue from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got answer from this question
[Set a return value as variable in window batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22817571/set-a-return-value-as-variable-in-window-batch)

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "sql=c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe"
for /f "usebackq" %%a in (`%sql% -u root -ss -e "select COUNT^(*^) FROM browser" form_generator`) do set TESTVAR=%%a
if %TESTVAR% LSS 1 echo whatever
pause
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.